# Deploying Java via Configuration Manager / SCCM / SMS

Tags: java, sccm, sms, deployment, configuration-management

So my package is working. Problem is, it doesn't uninstall the old version during the install. If I run the install on the local system it works fine.

Here is the command line I'm using:

jre-6u16-windows-i586-s.exe /quiet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command line we use is

```
160_11\jre-6u11-windows-i586-p-s.exe /qn JAVAUPDATE=0 AUTOUPDATECHECK=0 REBOOT=Suppress
```

This does remove the previous point release, but doesn't remove previous major releases (eg if we previously had 1.6 u05 on the machine that would be upgraded, but the 1.5.x version would be left.

We do this for backwards compatibility (which is always the major problem with Java) reasons.